# Can you use 頂いてもいい interchangeably with 頂けますか？

Tags: meaning, nuances

Like for Eg. I know 写真を取って頂けますか is correct. I am only aware of て+もいいfor standard verbs like 行ってもいい and not for receiving like もらう or 頂く so is 写真を取って頂いてもいい fine?

Any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

With the polite suffix, yes. Most people will find とって頂いてもいいですか politer and safer as to the point you said than とって頂けませんか, (though I personally find it less intuitive than とって もらっても いいですか).

If you find the former more or less wordy, 写真をおねがいしてもいいですか will work instead.